# TextInputLayout password toggle while keep pressed

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm using a `TextInputLayout` in my layout for a password field. Everything works file and password and plain toggles correctly when I press password toggle button. Whenever I click password toggle button, content switches between plain and password mode.

But I wonder if it is possible to change show password mode to keeping toggle password button pressed rather than clicking. It means as long as I keep password toggle button pressed, I see plain content and when I release button, content changes back to password mode. Do you have any idea if this is possible?

**UPDATE**

If you add this to your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/pin_hint"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility_eye"
    app:hintEnabled="true"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    app:errorEnabled="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLength="16"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and use this drawable as `password_visibility_eye.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_on" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off"  />
</selector>
```

You can click on eye button and switch between plain and password mode in your layout's edit (no code is needed). I like to change this behavior to **show password while keeping toggle password down**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnTouchListener on your toggle button.

```
  // this goes wherever you setup your button listener:
  button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           //here your onPressed state
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           //here your onReleased state
        }

        return true;
     }
  });
```

Comment: `TextInputLayout` automatically switches toggle state. assuming this code will prevent this behavior, how I need to change its toggle button?

Comment: Updated and added layout.

Comment: for me, it returns both ActionEvent Down followed by After. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Anything is possible with code.

Just do something like:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, android.view.MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
            // enable it
        }

        if (event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
            // disable it
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```